# Does Swabian have English influences?

Tags: etymology, history, dialect, swabian

Many variations of the swabian dialect contain words and pronunciations that to me always subtly sounded like influenced by modern english.

One of the more prominent examples is the pronunciation of "fünf" exactly like english "five" in some areas of the Black Forest.

Is this historically possible at all? I can't see how really. Is it coincidence?

> Übersetzung (siehe [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/translating-posts-as-a-community-norm)):
>
> Viele Schwäbische Dialekte haben Wort- und Aussprachebesonderheiten, die für mich immer subtil wie von modernem Englisch beeinflusst klangen.
>
> Eins der prominentesten Beispiele ist die Art, wie in manchen Schwarzwalddialekten das Wort "Fünf" ausgesprochen wird - nämlich exakt wie das englische "five".
>
> Ist das historisch überhaupt möglich? Soweit ich sehen kann, eigentlich nicht. Ist es Zufall?

Comment: It's the same in Franconian. I guess one reason could be that the languages or dialects share same roots and High German developed into another direction.

Comment: Ich denke, es ist eher Zufall, sprich es gab in beiden Sprachen ähnliche Lautverschiebungsmuster. Vielleicht kann jemand den Herrn Bachmann fragen: http://www.ghv-lichtenstein.de/Pressestimmen_GEA_1992_11_11_Mundart_Schwaebisch_Englisch.htm

Comment: @splattne danke für den Link, sehr interessant! Dem müßte man mal nachgehen - er ist inzwischen bestimmt in Rente...

Comment: I have the impression that "Swabian" or "Allemannisch" and English have little in common. [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RrEQ8Ovw-Q](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RrEQ8Ovw-Q)

Comment: Given that Swabians were one of the notable groups to have emigrated to the US well over a hundred years ago there is also a chance some of those who returned or the contact between the original group and the migrants alone gave rise to some mixing of the language.

Comment: In Saarlandish (rhine-franconian) and English, "my house is green" / "mei Haus is grien" has the same pronounciation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found an article in a local Swabian magazine. It's in two parts, the PDF versions are available on the website http://www.schwaben-kultur.de/ - [here](http://www.schwaben-kultur.de/pdfs/2007-2.pdf) (PDF, page 23) and [here](http://www.schwaben-kultur.de/pdfs/2007-4.pdf) (PDF, page 18).

The author mentions some astounding similarities between Swabian and English, for example:

> Hören heißt schwäbisch »lisna«, englisch »listen« wird ohne »t« gesprochen wie das schwäbische Wort.
>
> [...]
>
> »Wet« heißt englisch »naß«, »naß machen«, »nasse Stelle«. »A Wette« ist schwäbisch eine nasse Stelle in der Wiese

He claims to have a collection of about 300 examples and he has two attempts to explain:

> Woher kommen diese Ähnlichkeiten zwischen der Mundart der Schwaben an Donau und Neckar und der Sprache der Angelsachsen in Britannien? Zwei Vermutungen liegen nahe.
>
> Erstens: Im bäuerlichen Reden, fern aller Schriftsprache und Schulweisheit, hat sich bei den Schwaben Allgemeingermanisches besonders ursprünglich erhalten. Daher
>   Ähnlichkeiten zum Englischen als einer germanischen Sprache. Warum aber dann nicht zum Dänischen oder Niederländischen als germanischen Sprachen?
>
> Zweite Vermutung: Angeln und Schwaben stammen aus derselben Urheimat in Jütland. Darauf weisen alte Sagen und Bodenfunde. Schwäbisch gehört auch zu den nordgermanischen Dialekten. In vorchristlicher Zeit gehörten die Angeln zu den schwebischen Völkern. So kannten von allen germanischen Stämmen nur Angeln und Schwaben Männernamen mit dem Schwabennamen als Stammsilbe: Schwabbrecht, Schwabbert, Schwäbhart und Schwäbher(i).
>
> Diese Namen deuten auf eine alte Verbindung der beiden Volksstämme.
>
> In nachchristlicher Zeit wanderten Angeln und Schwaben in verschiedene Richtungen aus, aber die Sprachverwandtschaft zeigt sich noch, vor allem dort, wo die schwäbische
>   Mundart wenig von der deutschen Schriftsprache beeinflußt wurde. »Grilla« heißt schwäbisch wie angelsächsisch nicht »Würstchen braten«, sondern »schrill tönen, in hohen Tönen kreischen«. Das Schwäbische ist sehr konservativ, es bewahrt zum Teil den germanischen Lautstand schon über zweitausend Jahre, zum Beispiel in »hoach« (hoch).

Comment: Wow, answers like this are why I love the StackExchange network and why I am particularly interested in this site. On a side note for fun: There is a myth going around that swabians are scottish being cast out because of greed" :D

Comment: On a similar note, the Scottish word "Bairn" (Kind) seems to be derived from the Scandinavian "barn." So it seems that there is a Scandinavian influence in the English language that somehow found its way to Swabia.

Comment: @TomAu *Of course* there is a Norse influence in English. It is said that during the times of the Danelaw Vikings could easily converse with the locals of what's now London. Anglo-Saxon at the time must have been a lot closer to the common Proto-Germanic language than it became after the Norman rule.